# Validating array file input

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-validate

How can I validate an array of file `input` with `jquery.validate` plugin?

The code works fine with single file, but not with multiple upload, where `name=""` is an array.

**jQ:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#Main").validate({
            rules: {
                pic: { required:true, accept: "jpg|jpeg" }
            }}
        );
    });
</script>
```

**Single upload:**

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
        <td>Fotografija 1:</td>
        <td> <input type="file" class="fup" name="pic" /> </td>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

**Multiple upload**

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
            <td>Fotografija 1:</td>
            <td> <input type="file" class="fup" name="pic[]" /> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Fotografija 2:</td>
            <td> <input type="file" class="fup" name="pic[]" /> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Fotografija 3:</td>
            <td> <input type="file" class="fup" name="pic[]" /> </td>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: read [this](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
 $("input.fup").each(function(){
       $(this).rules("add", {
           required:true, 
           accept: "jpg|jpeg"
       });                    
 });
```

For detail see **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931687/using-jquery-validate-plugin-to-validate-multiple-form-fields-with-identical-nam/4136430#4136430)**

**[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227410/how-to-validate-multiple-input-type-files-with-jquery-validator-plugin)** is another resource.

Comment: It still works just for the first file input in my case. Other two ("fotografija1, fotografija2") are not validated. :/

Comment: It only validates the first input when the `name` attribute is used multiple times.  This plugin requires that naming be unique; there is no workaround!  The first question you linked to in your answer is about editing the core of the plugin itself.

Comment: Answer should be fixed or deleted.  Your first link says to edit the plugin itself, which only proves this cannot be done with this plugin.  The second link shows unique names, which is not what the OP is doing here. Finally, read the first comment on this answer above... proof:  [your solution just does not work when field name is repeated.  https://jsfiddle.net/gbxnadwo/](https://jsfiddle.net/gbxnadwo/)

Answer (score -2):

Have some issue here

```
"pic[]" {your rules}
```

and

```
rules("add)
```

wokring only for first element in array.

===

ok i found out solution:
you should fix `jquery.validate.js`

Find `checkForm` function

and replace it to:

```
        checkForm: function() {
        this.prepareForm();
        for ( var i = 0, elements = (this.currentElements = this.elements()); elements[i]; i++ ) {
            if (this.findByName( elements[i].name ).length != undefined && this.findByName( elements[i].name ).length > 1) {
                for (var cnt = 0; cnt < this.findByName( elements[i].name ).length; cnt++) {
                    this.check( this.findByName( elements[i].name )[cnt] );
                }
            } else {
                this.check( elements[i] );
            }
        }
        return this.valid();
    },
```

Comment: I have tried to modify the validate.js but it was not working for me